# Scoket io sends new data along with new data

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, socket.io

This is my server code

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');   
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept,x-auth');
next();
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('New User is connected...');
var sock = function() {

  var callback = function(data) {
    console.log('checkin data sending');
    socket.emit('checkInDetected', data);
    console.log(data);
   }
  socket.on("checkInDetected", callback);
    return function() {
      socket.removeListener("checkInDetected", callback);
    };
}();
var sock1 = function() {
  var callback2 = function(data) {
    console.log('seding checkout data');
    socket.emit('checkOutDetected',data);
    console.log(data);
  }
  socket.on("checkOutDetected",callback2);
  return function() {
    socket.removeListener("checkOutDetected", callback2);
  }
  }();
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('disconnected');
            //sock();
    });
    socket.on('disconnected', function(){
      socket.disconnect();
    });
});
server.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Server Started on Port 3000');
});
```

Client side code

```
export default class ScreenTwo extends Component {
constructor(props) {
name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name,
}
componentDidMount() {
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'url',
        data: {
        'name': this.state.name
      }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({
    userid: response.data.userid
  });
  console.log(this.state.userid);
});
this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://13.126.210.35:3000');
 DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('regionDidEnter', (data) => {
this.socket.emit('checkInDetected',
          {
            'userid': this.state.userid,
            'name': this.state.name,
            'location': 'Bandra'
          }
           );
}
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('regionDidExit', () => {
this.socket.emit('checkOutDetected',
    {
      'name': this.state.name,
      'userid': this.state.userid
    }
     );
goBack() {
delete this.state.name;
delete this.state.userid;
delete this.props.navigation.state.params.name;
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.name);
this.socket.emit('disconnected',
{
}
);
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
render() {
const { state } = this.props.navigation;
if (this.state.RegionExit === false) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.backbutton}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.goBack()}
              hitSlop={{ top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 }}
            >
              <Image
              source={BackArrow}
              style={{ width: 20 }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View sytle={styles.Title}>
            <View style={styles.TitleAndBar}>
              <View
              style={[styles.TitleBarRed, this.state.RegionEntry && styles.TitleBarGreen]}
              />
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.titleText}>Rapid</Text>
                <Text style={styles.titleText}>Out</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.statusView}>
              <Text style={styles.StatusText}>Status:</Text>
              <Text style={[styles.StatusOut, this.state.RegionEntry && styles.StatusIn]}>
              {this.state.status}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.Location}>
              <Text style={styles.LocationText}>You are at:</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.LocationNameTitle}>
              <Text
              style={[styles.LocationName, this.state.RegionEntry && styles.LocationNameGreen]}
              >{this.state.station}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
    </View>
    );
}
```

I have a react native app sending name and user ID, it contains two screens where i send name from the textinput input in first screen to second screen using react navigation. Then setState to change name string in second screen during componentDidMount. 
Then while emitting on socket it emits old names along with the new name, even though there is no local storage where it is stored. Yet it emits all the old and new names.

The question is why am i getting old data along with new data in socket?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: The question is why am i receiving old data along with new data using socket?

Comment: Please post your client as well

Comment: did, please let me know any mistakes in the code

Comment: Lol, turns out my BLE peripheral was causing multiple requests, sorted that, but I cannot access the name defined in static navigationOptions declared above in code.